# jQuery - toggle does not fire on page reload

Tags: jquery

i have this HTML.

```
<tr>
    <td width="75">Mon</td>
    <td class="bn_time" width="60">
        <input id="mon_open" name="mon_open" class="time" placeholder="opening time" />
    </td>
    <td class="bn_time" width="10" align="center">-</td>
    <td class="bn_time" width="100">
        <input id="mon_close" name="mon_close" class="time" placeholder="closing time" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" class="bn_holiday" hidden>Holiday</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mon_closed" id="mon_closed" class="bn_closed" />
        <label for="mon_closed">Closed</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

i am using this jQuery.

```
$('.bn_closed').on('change', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr('id');
    var day = id.slice(0,-7);
    var day_open = day+'_open';
    var day_close = day+'_close';
    var checked = element.is(':checked');
    var td = element.closest("td");
    td.siblings(".bn_time").toggle(!checked);
    td.siblings(".bn_holiday").toggle(checked);
});
```

to achieve the following.

```
if($('.bn_closed').is(':checked')) {
     //hide all <td> element with class bn_time
     //show <td> element with class bn_holiday
} else {
    //show all <td> element with class bn_time
    //hide <td> element with class bn_holiday
}
```

this works with change event of `.bn_closed` however when the page is reloaded and if the element with class `.bn_closed` is checked. the toggling does not comes into effect. what i want is the toggling should take place in the event of page reload too. how do i go with it?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.bn_closed').on('change', function() {
    // ...
}).change()
```

Comment: thank you, it is working, so what exactly does `.change()` does in here?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar You are welcome, it just triggers the change event.

Comment: okay so you mean, it triggers the change event on page load, instead of waiting for user to trigger the event.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Yes, it does so.